# How to change the Font Size in a whole react application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, font-size

I have created a react web application with the dropdown consist of font size.

My need is, if i select the Font Size "26" from the dropdown, then it should be applied to my whole project.Is there a way could it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personnally i would make a global style file with a styleSheet that i import on every component to use it. With this file you can use a variable from your storage (ex: font style) and apply it to all font-size directives.
Good luck !

Comment: can you please explain with the snippet?

Comment: I can try ! 
For example in my app i've a folder named "Helpers" and i have a file in it : "style.js"
In this file, i defined my whole app style :
`import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

let color_text = '#fff'
let color_button_text = '#262626'
...

export default StyleSheet.create({
    itemList: {
        height: 100,
        borderRadius: 10,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        marginVertical: 10
    },
    imageItem: {
        flex: 1
    }
...
})`
If you do the same you could use a variable to set the font size: redux / redux-persist